# How do I use a variable for a hyperlink

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I currently have the code in the picture provided.
I'm trying to make it where the cell (i, 2) is replaced with the hyperlink LINK.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTgsH.png)

```python
import gc
from hashlib import sha1
from turtle import end_fill
import gspread
import time
import xlsxwriter


gc = gspread.service_account()
spreadsheet = gc.open('ZuhairScraper')
sh = spreadsheet
worksheet = sh.worksheet('Main')
ws = worksheet



WalmartUPC_list = ws.col_values(1)
WalmartUPC_list.pop(0) # delete first value of a list
# WalmartUPC_list = WalmartUPC_list[1:] another way to remove the first value of a list
def hyperlink():
    for i in range(2, len(WalmartUPC_list)+2):
        time.sleep(1)
        LINK = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/" + ws.cell(i, 1).value
        print(LINK)
        #ws.update_cell(i, 2, link)
        ws.update_cell(i, 2, '=HYPERLINK({LINK},"LINK")')

hyperlink()
```

For clarification, the problem I am having is that whenever I do

```
ws.update_cell(i, 2, '=HYPERLINK({LINK},"LINK")')
```

it outputs the literal word "link" in the hyperlink format.
instead of the actual link that I'm trying to output

how would I make a hyperlink using the data in the variable LINK?

Answer (score 2):

Hi what you miss is the `f` letter in front of the f-string to replace the keyword `{LINK}` with the actual content of the variable.

```py
ws.update_cell(i, 2, '=HYPERLINK({LINK},"LINK")')
```

Which becomes:

```py
ws.update_cell(i, 2, f'=HYPERLINK({LINK},"LINK")')
                     ^ here
```

Here is the documentation about f-strings

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/